# EE upgrade failing to 2.9.2

Tags: upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I've tried to upgrade EE 2.8.2 to a 2.9.2 in the dev environment but it semes to keep on failing.
i looked it up and seen some suggestions saying disable javascript and others to disable third party addons. tried them all and no luck.

As a test, i've made a clean install of EE 2.8.2 and tried to upgrade it to 2.9.2 get the same problem!

I follow all the steps of the upgrade documentation here until step 6: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html
I reach to the "agreement" button i click "I agree"
i get to the page index.php?C=wizard&M=do_update&language=english&ajax_progress=yes
and then nothing anymore

Is there a setting i'm missing?

PHP and MYSQL version both meet the ee requirment.
Is there something else i could be missing?

[image]

Comment: I think this is one for an EllisLab support ticket.

Comment: How come? i dont have support account i don't think you can just make a ticket can you?

Comment: Yes, you need a support account. I just say that it's best for them to look at because I've never personally seen this before, and it will likely be best solved by someone actually getting into your dev environment and seeing what's happening.